# Does close(2) safely stop F_NOTIFY signals?

Tags: linux

Does `close(fd)` safely stop the generation of signals that were started with `fcntl(fd, F_NOTIFY, ...)`?

`man 2 fcntl` doesn't say what happens if the directory being watched is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would have to. When a notification signal is sent, the `si_fd` field of the `siginfo_t` argument contains the FD of the open directory. If it could send notifications for closed directories, how could `si_fd` be interpreted? If you opened another directory, it could get the same FD, and then this value would be ambigous.

The documentation of this option recommends using `inotify` instead. This doesn't use file descriptors so this issue doesn't come up.

Comment: I agree with your argument that stopping notifications is the only reasonable behavior. However, would it be safe for an application to rely on it? Or could an OS implementation assume that the application always uses `fcntl` to turn off notifications (which *is* documented) before closing the FD? (And e.g., terminate the process if it doesn't follow the protocol.)

Comment: Anything is possible, but it's not consistent with how things work in general. Anything involving an FD would be expected to be invalidated when the FD is closed.

Comment: You could always check the implementation. I expect that the data structure that the FD points to contains a list of the notifications. So when the FD is closed, that list goes away.